# How do I use the > character in a Sublime Text 2 snippet's tabTrigger?

Tags: sublimetext2, code-snippets

I'm writing snippets that require -> to be part of the tabTrigger.  However, they seem to be ignored entirely.  My list of triggers disappears after the hyphen character.

I know that $ can be added by escaping with a backslash, but that doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: That's interesting.  I just wrote a quick snippet, triggered by `>`, `->`, and `-->`.  All of them worked just like I would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can use `&gt;`, instead of >.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is those characters are defined as word separators. So, for the purpose of auto completion, there are no characters there to build the autocomplete (or snippet) list. That being said, the tab triggers still work fine.

Comment: I don't think that's it.  Adding or Removing `>` from my word separators list does not impact my ability to use it as a tab trigger.

Comment: Hmm okay, I know that was a solution for someone using `$` in a tab trigger. But apparently there's something extra with the `>`